# Manually register a plugin

Tags: plugins, pentaho, kettle, pdi

I'm trying to run a transformation using PDI embedded in Java code but I get an error about missing plugin (looks like it is the Abort step).

I know I can use `KETTLE_PLUGIN_BASE_FOLDERS` so that PDI loads it automatically (that works), but in order to make my app simpler I would like to manually register this plugin using Java, how can I do that?

I'm following examples provided here https://github.com/pentaho/pdi-sdk-plugins/tree/master/kettle-sdk-embedding-samples

```
2019/08/14 17:03:07 - Could not find on destination DB.0 - ERROR (version 8.2.0.7-719, build 8.2.0.7-719 from 2019-06-24 02.06.35 by buildguy) : Can't run transformation due to plugin missing
2019/08/14 17:03:07 - Could not find on source DB.0 - ERROR (version 8.2.0.7-719, build 8.2.0.7-719 from 2019-06-24 02.06.35 by buildguy) : Can't run transformation due to plugin missing
2019/08/14 17:03:07 - Could not find on destination DB.0 - ERROR (version 8.2.0.7-719, build 8.2.0.7-719 from 2019-06-24 02.06.35 by buildguy) : Error initializing step [Could not find on destination DB]
2019/08/14 17:03:07 - Could not find on source DB.0 - ERROR (version 8.2.0.7-719, build 8.2.0.7-719 from 2019-06-24 02.06.35 by buildguy) : Error initializing step [Could not find on source DB]
2019/08/14 17:03:07 - Could not find on destination DB 2.0 - ERROR (version 8.2.0.7-719, build 8.2.0.7-719 from 2019-06-24 02.06.35 by buildguy) : Can't run transformation due to plugin missing
2019/08/14 17:03:07 - Could not find on destination DB 2.0 - ERROR (version 8.2.0.7-719, build 8.2.0.7-719 from 2019-06-24 02.06.35 by buildguy) : Error initializing step [Could not find on destination DB 2]
2019/08/14 17:03:07 - Abort.0 - ERROR (version 8.2.0.7-719, build 8.2.0.7-719 from 2019-06-24 02.06.35 by buildguy) : Can't run transformation due to plugin missing
2019/08/14 17:03:07 - Abort.0 - ERROR (version 8.2.0.7-719, build 8.2.0.7-719 from 2019-06-24 02.06.35 by buildguy) : Error initializing step [Abort]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To register a plugin you must set a system property, `KETTLE_PLUGIN_CLASSES`, with the fully qualified class name of the plugins meta-class before you initialize your KettleEnvironment. The property can be a comma-separated string of all plugins you wish to register.

This is an example of how to register a plugin:

```
  void initEnv() {
    // Register plugins here
    System.setProperty("KETTLE_PLUGIN_CLASSES","org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.jsoninput.JsonInputMeta");
    try {
      KettleEnvironment.init();
    } catch (KettleException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

This example registers the `JSON Input` step which is a core plugin. In order for PDI to successfully load the plugin, it's jar-file must be available on the classpath.